# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in object + properties

Tags: javascript, html, object, properties, console.log

```
function RespondClick(){
var both = ();
both.result = document.getElementById("username").value;
both.results = document.getElementById("userame").value;
console.log(both);
```

Hi,
I am new to javascript getting a error not sure object or properties scripted appropriately.

So I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, I'm extremely new to programming and my school is 
online so I'm on my own. Based on my book, this code should work? I keep getting the error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>      
<div>
<label>First Name:</label><input type="text" id="username">
</div>
<div>
<label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="userame">
</div>
<script  type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("clickIt").addEventListener("click", RespondClick),
function RespondClick(){
var both = ();
both.result = document.getElementById("username").value;
both.results = document.getElementById("userame").value;
console.log(both);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be most appreciative! Thanks!

Comment: `var both = ();` <= should be `{}` for an object.  Looks like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: `var both = ();` most likely should be `var both = {};` (`{}` instead of `()`).

Second thing: your function is not closed. You need to add `}` after `console.log(both)`.

Third thing: you should replace the `,` after `...addEventListener("click", RespondClick)` with `;`

Fourth thing: it looks like you are missing an element with the id `clickIt` you want to handle a click on. I just created a dummy to make it work by adding `<button id="clickIt">click</button>` after the hello.

Applying this to your example it should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<button id="clickIt">click</button>
<div>
    <label>First Name:</label><input type="text" id="username">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="userame">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById('clickIt').addEventListener('click', RespondClick);
    function RespondClick() {
        var both = {};
        both.result = document.getElementById('username').value;
        both.results = document.getElementById('userame').value;
        console.log(both);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: function RespondClick(){   and console.log(both);  }  closed now get new error              Uncaught ReferenceError: RespondClick is not defined

Comment: I updated my answer. please check you example for the missing element.

Comment: var both = {};     console.log(both);}

Comment: You should be able to use my example code by copying and pasting it into your target file. I tested it.

Comment: Great Help for leaner like me   thanks for you Mr Benjamin Eckardt .

Comment: You are welcome. I would appreciate accepting the answer. ;)